# How are functions ordered when calling multi defined functions with the same name

Tags: elixir

Hi guys I'm just following along with the screencasts from http://learnelixir.tv which are fantastic, this is my first functional based programming language but I'm really enjoying it.

I'm currently learning about lists and we make a custom length function like so:

```
defmodule MyList do
    def length(list) do
        length(list, 0)
    end

    defp length([], count) do
        count
    end

    defp length([_|t], count) do
        length(t, count + 1)
    end
end
```

Which works great

```
MyList.length([1, 2, 3, 4])
// 4
```

So from what I understand is, we originally pass in the first call to the non-private function, a call to `length-private` now does the virtual machine go ok theres 2 versions, one that accepts an empty array, and one that takes one thats not empty?

How come it doesn't jump right into `length([], count)` first and return `count // 0` instead it goes for the last declared `length` function,

(small side question)

How is count shared between the 2 private length functions, and how is `[_|t]` mutating the array and sharing it between the 2 functions as well?

Answer (score 5):

It uses what's called [pattern matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching) to pick the right function. So it checks if the first argument is an empty list and if so, it will use the first function, if not, it will use the second. You can read about it [here](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/pattern-matching.html)

- The [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) (it's not an array) and the counter are not mutated. You just use different values for every function call. Here's how it works:
- When you first call your function, it does pattern matching amongst public functions, since there is only one and it matches any function call with 1 argument, it gets called.
- Then it calls `length(list, 0)` which does the pattern matching again but including private functions and since it has two arguments and the first one is not an empty list, it goes to the third function.
- The third function in its turn calls the `length` method again, but passes different arguments, which, in your example, would be `length([1,2,3], 1)`.
- It goes until the list is empty, so it would call `length([1,2], 2)`, `length([1], 3)` and so on.
- When it calls `length([], 4)` the second function gets called because the first argument matches. The second function simply returns the counter, which would be 4, which is the final value that you get.

So as you see, there is no mutating going on and the process is called [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion)